# Autosave EditText android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I implements autosave for EditText ?
I need to save when user stop to insert text.
What's the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: hi enfix, for this use `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend something along these lines:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                int count)
    {
      prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
    }

    @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                    int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }
  });
```

Comment: I need to save on DB. Can i do this onTextChanged method ? It's the best way ?

Comment: sure you can save into a database if you don't wish to save into preferences storage